# Connecting UIViews to json response and vice versa

Tags: ios, json, swift, uikit

I'm currently making an app that will essentially include a main UIView with dynamic stackviews that receive data from a JSON and when the user edits the textfields on that view, I want the received json to be edited accordingly and then get submitted to the server. The view looks like the below screenshot:

[image]

The first and second tab are custom stackviews that can close and open. Originally every stackview contains a button that appends custom views to the inner stackview of the current tab. The user can either click the edit on each custom inner view, which opens a hidden view under it that includes textfields that he can fill or either delete the subview entirely.

I want the json that is traded between the app and the server to look like this:

```
{
    "firstTab": [
        {
            "itemA": false,
            "itemB": 2,
            "itemC": "type",
            "itemD": "tt"
        },
        {
            "itemA": false,
            "itemB": 2,
            "itemC": "type",
            "itemD": "dd"
        }
    ],
    "secondTab": [
        {
            "itemA": "test",
            "itemB": 2,
            "itemC": "a"
        },
        {
            "itemA": "test",
            "itemB": 2,
            "itemC": "type"
        },
        {
            "itemA": "test",
            "itemB": 2,
            "itemC": "type"
        }
    ]
}
```

where each item is a textfield inside the appropriate stackview.

The first time the app opens, the app has to receive a draft json from the server like the above and make the appropriate elements in the stackviews. I have mapped the json to a codable but I can't seem to render the UI efficiently without resorting to a custom solution. Is there an efficient way to do this in Swift?

Essentially, I want to map the dynamic fields to json values and be able to edit those values. A two way connection between the UI and the local json file. Is there a native way to do that in swift? Or a recommended library?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using structs that conform to `Codable / Encodable`. It is probably the cleaniest way.

These protocols serve (or can serve) as a JSON wrapper for both coding and decoding.

So you would have a struct like so:

```
struct FirstTab: Encodable {
    let itemA: Bool
    let itemB: Int
    let itemC: String
    let itemD: String
}
```

And you would change the struct with information given from the user interaction i.e.: `UITextField`.

This struct can now be coded / decoded trough `JSONEncoder`

Please see:

`JSONEncoder` documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder

`Codable` protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

`Decodable` protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable

`Encodable` protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable

And importantly, `Encoding and Decoding Custom Types` documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can see things more clearly now. My only question is, what is a clean way to assign a textfield to a certain field in the struct? Since both tabs can have many sets of items, I want to set for example value itemC of the 10th element in the firstTab array to "test1". How would I achieve that? How do you setup each dynamic uitextfield to know which value to update.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question, but you would use something like: `let variable: String? = myTextfield.text`